# What should SO's motto be?

Tags: discussion, fun

What should SO's motto be?

Comment: StackOverflow: We don't need no damn motto.

Comment: StackOverflow: We don't need no stinkin' <strike>badges</strike> motto.

Comment: StackOverflow: Where theres 'not-programming-related' theres 'closed'.

Comment: Stack overflow | error: stack still growing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it used to be fun, but things changed too much since those good old days.

Answer (score 56):

**Stack Overflow**:

- Putting more palms to face than a Rick James tribute video
- We have more important things to do, but they don't come with avatars
- You ask, we answer. We ask, you answer
- OMG, ponies!
- This better be programming related
- Because PonyOverflow.com keeps taking me back to this weirdo's profile page
- We RTFM so you don't have to
- Where RTFM is discouraged, but RTFFAQ is gospel
- Is the podcast up yet?
- You should totally drop that and try jQuery
- Stop now if you plan on asking how to parse XML with regex
- It's like folding@home, only it runs on bored developers
- We were smart enough not to use a domain name that advertised sex changes
- Yes, we **do** need stinkin' badges!
- The first rule of Stack Overflow is you do not talk about Stack Overflow (you talk about Stack Overflow on Meta Stack Overflow)

**Meta Stack Overflow**:

- Status declined
- Yes, we know you hate the colors
- Closed as exact duplicate
- Whatever you're requesting, Sampson has probably already written a greasemonkey script
- The first rule of meta is you do not talk about meta (you talk about Stack Overflow)
- Its always Friday afternoon in Iceland

**Server Fault**:

- We should be too busy being sysadmins, yet here we are

**Super User**:

- This should be Community Wiki
- Must have ...
- There's a good chance your work filter has this blocked
- Are you ready to unleash the fury!?
- Have you tried forcing an unexpected reboot?
- FORMAT C: and try again
- Just wait until Alex starts looking here for new TDWTF.com material

Comment: You should have posted these separately - I would have voted them all up :-D

Comment: You left out **"NEVER PARSE XML WITH REGULAR EXPRESSIONS!!!!!"**

Comment: Oh this list will continue to grow. and Kyle, I could have posted them all as separate and gotten voted up for all of them, but you would go through all your votes too easily. Plus I'm at rep limit anyway today.

Comment: I should also note that I have absolutely no idea how to be snarky towards ServerFault

Comment: if you keep editing this, you'll end up wikifying it

Comment: Kyle: I thought that was only if a certain number of users revised, not if it was just one person.

Comment: Please, one motto per post so that we can vote.

Comment: @TheTXI: nope, multiple edits by the owner will trigger wiki too, look at the second bullet point under "how does a post become a community wiki post": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow/128436#128436

Comment: **It's Like Folding@Home, Only It Runs On Bored Developers**

Comment: Hmm...looks like if I edit it one more time it should probably flip. Overall it doesn't matter (it's not like I'm earning rep from it now anyway ). My idea box is running out of items in it now anyways.

Comment: absolutely brilliant!

Comment: Speaking of Greasemonkey: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7739/so-family-quick-reference-to-qs-as-and-favs-last-update-07-21-2009

Comment: "It is more productive than watching porn."

Comment: Chacha102: You're going to have to provide facts to back that claim up.

Comment: TXI: That's the sad part...

Comment: Server Fault: Because cowering in the corner by ourselves is lonely.

Comment: @Joel But now, you can be lonley together!

Comment: StackOverflow: Forcing you to use UTC to tell when to start answering questions again.

Comment: To be fair, if you want a sex-change, why WOULDN'T you go to the experts?

Comment: ServerFault: Down, not across.

Comment: +1 for **This better be programming related**

Answer (score 44):

Stack Overflow:

- The Internet's most reliable source for answers with numbers next to them
- Like Yahoo! Answers, only good
- Turning procrastinating programmers into a resource since 2008

Meta:

- Questionable answers to unanswerable questions
- If Jeff thinks meta-discussion is a waste of time, why does he have the most rep?
- The place to go in while waiting for SO to refresh

Comment: I like "Turning procrastinating programmers into a resource since 2008"

Answer (score 31):

Stack Overflow: doing others' work for points instead of doing your own for dollars.

Answer (score 20):

Stack Overflow: More expert, less sex change.

Comment: That's not necessarily a good thing

Answer (score 16):

Stack Overflow: Your free time just went in the corner and shot itself.

Answer (score 16):

Stack Overflow: Get back to work.

Answer (score 14):

I believe to this point, from Jeff and Joel, it has been "Expert's Exchange, without the evil."

Comment: I don't know. I saw something about it, but they wanted money so I turned back.

Comment: +1. Though it could maybe be "Expert's Exchange, but fun to use"

Answer (score 14):

Stack Overflow:  Let me google that for ya.

Answer (score 12):

[StackOverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) - Because [JonSkeet.com](http://jonskeet.com) was taken.

Comment: And how many people are going to jonskeet.com now, just to check?

Comment: Not me, as I'm too lazy to copy it into my address bar.

Comment: @kd304: I hope my edit assists your laziness to an adequate degree.

Comment: Okay, I'll bite.

Answer (score 10):

Stack Overflow: Google Me
Meta: To teach you by-design
Server Fault: Down due DNS troubles
Super User: Run as root and it will work

Answer (score 10):

"No boat programmers allowed"

Comment: Hahaha...That's an old joke.

Comment: .. but I like it!!!

Answer (score 8):

Stack Overflow: because we believe you have too much time on your hands...

Comment: That much is true. I've somehow managed 1000 rep points in a week. 80 more weeks at that rate and I'll be knocking on your door! I don't think its going to happen. Project crunch time coming up over the next month.

Comment: Colin: Even if the skeeter decided to just up and stop, the amount of inertia in his answer catalog is enough to keep propelling him forward for who knows how long.

Comment: 80 more weeks with jon skeet locked away without net access and his existing posts locked from being upvoted?

Answer (score 8):

Stack Overflow: Providing Computer Geeks with Friends since 2008.

Comment: btw this is not an attack on computer geeks...I myself am one.

Answer (score 7):

Harnessing nerd power since 2008

<strike>5</strike> 0 days without a rollback war

Comment: Prefer "geek" over "nerd"

Comment: Really?  I always call myself a nerd ... but I'm from the Revenge of the Nerds generation. :)

Comment: I don't think we'd ever get 5 days.

Comment: @devinb I think we did once after the RAID Controller failed :) http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/tuesday-outage-its-raid-tastic/

Answer (score 6):

We're not [expert sex change](http://expertsexchange.com).

Answer (score 6):

"*Programming Related*"

You know, the opposite of 'Closed as Not Programming Related' ; )

Answer (score 6):

**Super User**: All computer related questions are welcome here!

<sub>Except consoles, videogames, iPhones, smartphones, cellphones, Androids, Blackberries, Facebook, Gmail, Twitter, Wordpress, other websites, web services, mp3 players, iPads, discussions, shopping lists, recommendations, arguments, "must have" lists, Web design, programming, servers, waffles, unicorns, etc...</sub>

Comment: Sounds about right.

Answer (score 5):

StackOverflow.com: Preventing developers from doing actual work since 2008!

Answer (score 5):

StackOverflow.com: Because developers need something non-lethal to do while their code is [compiling](http://xkcd.com/303/).

Answer (score 4):

You can check out anytime you like, but you can never leave

No, really, [the first time is free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/programmer-jokes-whats-your-best-one/235212#235212)!

Answer (score 4):

"Shoot first, ask questions later, do some work eventually"

Comment: +1 assuming it's understood as "Troubleshoot first, ask questions later, do some work eventually" ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow:  Access to this much knowledge will nearly compensate for the time it absorbs.

Answer (score 3):

Since Brad posted his awesome suggetsion as a comment instead of an answer...

**Stack Overflow:** Badges? We ain't got no badges. We don't need no badges! I don't have to show you any stinkin' badges!

(From [The Treasure of the Sierra Madre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinking_badges))

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow: Do your own damn homework.

Answer (score 2):

"Stack Overflow - Better than experts exchange"

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow:  Where Violated Access and Faulty Segmentation Collide

Answer (score 1):

"divide et overflow"

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on the coattails and playing on the words of experts-exchange in parody, and also based on the concepts of beauty and sex sell, we can try these:

**Stack Overflow**: When Expert Sex Change won't give you one, we'll give it to you free! (C'mon people, we're talking about accounts here.)

**Stack Overflow**: True friends for when you can't keep a profile on [BeautifulPeople.com](http://beautifulpeople.com) for more than 27 seconds.

**Stack Overflow**: An alternative form of excitement for when a sex change is prohibitively expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow: see Recursion - No, wait!

Answer (score 0):

Super User: The "must-have" knowledge exchange resource.

Answer (score -1):

Stack Overflow? The name speaks for itself!

Answer (score -1):

Stack overflow | error: stack still growing.

Stack overflow | our stack is still growing.

Answer (score -1):

I like:

- **Stack OverflE??^D8p??E?f.?s??$??giL?]??E??^D8p?s???**

Answer (score -2):

Super User: Reboot, Reinstall, Red Hat.

Comment: "Must have" Reboot, Reinstall, Redhat apps

Answer (score -3):

**Where questions come to get answered, or closed!**