# SO-Family Quick-Reference to Q's, A's, and Fav's

Tags: discussion, search, stack-exchange, addon

#### Download Source:

http://www.sampsonresume.com/labs/so-bigbox.user.js

#### Installation:

1. Install [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) for Firefox.
2. Restart Firefox.
3. Return here and click the 'download source' link.
4. Once downloaded, click *Tools* > *Greasemonkey* > *Manage User Scripts*
5. Select "so-bigbox" from the list, and add the following "Included Pages"

   1. `*stackoverflow*`
   2. `*serverfault*`
   3. `*superuser*`
6. That's it, you're done.

#### General Information:

Works on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), [Stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com), [Serverfault](http://www.serverfault.com), and [Super User](http://www.superuser.com). Determines your user-id automatically based upon the DOM. You can change it to any other id to spy on your friends.

```
var user_id = $("#hlinks a[href^='...']").next("a").attr("href").split("/")[2];

    user_id = 22656; /* What is Jon Skeet up to lately? 
                        Overwrites previous value. */
```

<strike>Upon page-load</strike> When the panel is opened for the first time after a page-load the script will request any lists you've explicitly declared as 'true' within your copy of the script. It will then add a toggle-bar to the bottom of  your screen (fixed). Clicking this bar will toggle the search-lists. Searches are now **case-insensitive**!

#### Configuration:

Comes with a list of configurable sources. If you don't want to search your own past answers, modify the sources-block:

```
var user_questions = true;
var user_answers   = false; /* I DO NOT want to search my answers */
var user_favorites = true;
```

Ships with a default cap of 100 recent items. This means your default lists will contain only the 200 most recent items. You can manually change this if you like:

```
var max_items = 100;
```

[image]

Comment: You might as well just take a branch off the Firefox development line and build a StackOverflow-enabled web browser.

Comment: I think Jonathan should definitely add "Stack Overflow's *un*official Grease Monkey" to his bio page.

Comment: I'd hate to sound like an idiot, but to make this accessible to more people, could you add step-by-step instruction on how to try it out? What to do with the JS file, and do you need something specific to use it? (Firefox? some FF extension? or any browser?)

Comment: Sorry, Jonik. You need the Greasemonkey plugin for firefox. Download that, then come back and click the link - greasemonkey will auto-install the script.

Comment: I've added an **Installation** section to the above post, Jonik. Hope that helps.

Comment: 100 recent items as default? Does this mean that there are scaling problems

Comment: This is really awsome and something I wanted since my first visit to these sites!  I would really love to use something like this with Google Chrome if possible

Comment: @JonathanSampson This script is awesome. Maybe you should put it up on http://userscripts.org/scripts/search?q=sofu&x=0&y=0 so more people can find it? You could use http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/data/data for the images, to keep people from hitting your server. Just a thought, thanks for the script.

Comment: After installation on FF6.0.2, nothing seems to have changed in my browser.

Comment: Is it on StackApps?

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, that is really cool.  I wish I could resize it myself though.

Comment: Yeah, resizing is something I thought about working into it.

Comment: You can manually set the height in the json-css located within the script.

Comment: Ug, that javascript stuff scares me...

Answer (score 1):

Not to toot my own horn, but this thing really is awesome. I'm finding it easy to jump back to questions I've recently answered just by clicking the toggle-bar, and looking to the top of my "Answers" list. I can see which favorites were recently updated by looking to the top of my favorites list, and the same goes for questions I've asked. This is great!

Comment: I think you did toot your own horn a bit, but it's ok, as this does look great! So +1. I like seeing which of my favourite questions have new answers/edits, and the search/filter thing works really smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks and works good, although doesn't work in GreaseKit (safari).

One recommendation I have is using a better search algorithm. Exact matching can get gruesome when you have a lot of questions/answers. I find the [quicksilver search/sort algorithm](http://orderedlist.com/demos/quicksilverjs/javascripts/quicksilver.js) to be particularly good, which was [ported to jQuery](http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-livesearch/) by John Resig himself.  It will make your code a bit longer, but will greatly improve searching for power-users, who are probably more likely to use this anyways.

Answer (score 0):

A feature request :) Could you add some more info about the recently changed questions..?

Now the tooltip shows the start of the question, but I think far more interesting would be the start of the most recent (or most recently edited) *answer*. And, at least, it would be useful to see who made the most recent change and when. For example "jul 15 at 10:18  Roubachof" like on the [favourites page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56285?tab=favorites#sort-top) - this could IMHO be shown all the time (i.e. not in the tooltip) somewhere near the question title, maybe in slightly smaller font and another colour.

Answer (score 0):

Love the script, but I found it hung a few times waiting for a response from your server, so I inlined the images. I couldn't figure out how to reuse the loading image so added it three 3 times. Happy to post the update if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I have a slight problem with this script. I modded it to show 300 items per (what can i say? i ask and favorite a lot of stuff) and it always seems to be spinning for my questions...

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work for me. I made sure to restart and add the sites, but I don't see anything

Comment: Look at the very bottom of your monitor...no new bar showed up?

Comment: Worked on Windows, will try again on Mac later