# Properly Releasing SO Tools onto SO, SF, and SU?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

I'm wondering how I should go about informing the users of SO, SF, and SU of particular scripts/tools that can enhance their experience here on Stack Overflow. Considering the small portion of us who participate actively on MetaSO, a mere mention here doesn't really get reach out enough.

What is the appropriate way to get the word out?

For instance: [Quick Reference to Q's, A's, and Fav's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7739/so-family-quick-reference-to-qs-as-and-favs-last-update-07-21-2009)

Answer (score 3):

I think Meta is the right place. If people are interested in "enhancing their experience" then they're likely to come here. Most users probably couldn't really care less - announcements would just get in the way, etc.

It would be nice to have another "discussion/feature-request/bug" tag of "tool-announce" or something similar. Then they'd be easy to group together - and maybe Jeff could highlight them on the podcast occasionally.

Comment: I like the idea about having a different tag used specifically for StackOverflow client-development.

Comment: we can certainly highlight this on the blog periodically!

Answer (score 3):

[Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) has been the place for this since 2010*. It's operated by Stack Exchange and has a UI that should be familiar to SE users.

<sup>* Nitpick for history buffs: Stack Apps [opened in 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-public-beta-starts/), but userscripts have [been welcome only since 2011](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/stack-apps-and-scripts/).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mr. Skeet...  The posts really belong here on META, but that certainly doesn't get the attention of some of the other folks.  It would be interesting if this was a topic for conversation in one of the upcoming PodCasts where they can describe what users have done to expand on the SO ui's, etc.  Maybe even a quick SO blog on it...

From recent experience (i.e. logo & turtles), the podcast seems to get quite a few folk's attention.

Comment: "Mr. Skeet" - chuckles

Comment: yep, and it can be mentioned in the podcast as well