# Notify us of changes to posts that are not our own

Tags: feature-request, edits, notifications, posts

It would be nice to be able to opt in to being notified of changes on other posts besides our own. I may just be lazy but it's inconvenient to have to periodically check other interesting posts manually, via the built in favorites or otherwise. I'd like to be notified of specific things like new comments and post edits so I don't have to waste my time eyeballing what's changed from last week and this week.

Opting in could be presented just like the notification check box that appears at the bottom of the Ask Question page.

Answer (score 1):

Click that little star next to the question. Then, it'll show up in [your Favorites tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59180?tab=favorites), and you can sort by "Recent." Use this for temporary bookmarks when you want to keep track of a question.

Comment: That's what I do. But I have my favorites available on every page (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7739) so I can quickly check updated items whenever I need to.

Comment: You would, you greasy monkey, you.

Comment: Updated my request. Favorites gets part of the way there but doesn't offer the granularity I'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Acivity Table and click on 'Edits to your posts'.

Comment: That shows me edits to *my* posts. I want to be notified when edits happen to posts made by *others*.