# List All My Questions

Tags: support, user-interface

Is there some **easy** way to list ALL of my questions on SO (without paging)?

I ask because aside from rep gained and lost, I always refer back to the answers to my questions.

I would also like to be able to search just my questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Firefox, you can install my greasemonkey script that allows you to see and search all of your favorites, questions, and answers.

[SO-Family Quick-Reference to Q's, A's, and Fav's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7739/so-family-quick-reference-to-qs-as-and-favs)

Answer (score 0):

At this moment there is no way to see all of you answers without paging through the list. There is also no simple way of searching only questions that you have posted (and I can't think of a simple way of doing it via Google either).

Comment: Of course there's a simple way ;) See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Through an answer to [Can I view favorites from all SE sites at one place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92734/can-i-view-favorites-from-all-se-sites-at-one-place/92735#92735) (2011-05-26) I found:

[Stack Exchange Network Profiles — Blog — Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-network-profiles/) (2011-04-08)

Finding my way today to my profile — from somewhere *other* than the main Stack Exchange site — wasn't immediately intuitive. I'll probably recall the routine as:

1. visit Stack Exchange, log in
2. in the header, click my name.