# Can I view favorites from all SE sites at one place

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

I have marked many questions as favorites across several SE sites. Sometimes I forget whether I visited any particular site or not but there some very good questions across those sites.

is there any way I can see all my favorites at one place from all SE sites?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not yet, but this is something I have put on our development calendar.

Of course you do have a network profile but it lacks a favorites tab.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-network-profiles/

Comment: I had at a look at network profile . But thats good if it gets implemented , will save a lot of time

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 7):

It's now possible to view favourites across the network in your [Stack Exchange profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/292874/ambo100?tab=favorites).

Comment: There is "Page Not Found" in that link.

Comment: This links to this users specific stack exchange profile. Not "your" profile. I don't know how to link to a users own profile but it should probably be possible and it would be great if someone could edit this answer to contain that link.

Comment: Actually, even adjusting for the UserID this just doesn't seem to work at all!

Comment: It looks like this page has been removed.