# Ability to search favourites and questions

Tags: feature-request

It would be useful to have an option to search favourites and questions we asked even if it was only title and tag search.

Comment: Search among your favourites or those favourited by others, asked by you?

Comment: Duplicate? - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff

Comment: @John Smithers - it's always nice to get a second opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Grease Monkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7739/so-family-quick-reference-to-qs-as-and-favs-last-update-07-21-2009) here that should do it.

Comment: The script does do the job, but having this added as a easy to use feature is the site's job, not the users'.