# Should a "fun" question be posted on Meta instead of SO?

Tags: discussion, questions

So the meta stuffs should goes to meta... like this very question.

But now that we have meta.stackoverflow, what about those occasionally humorous/fun question? should it be posted/moved to meta.so as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if this seems to be the way of doing things here with some fun questions having been moved to meta, I would not do that. Many people will never be on meta that are on SO, and rightly so. Meta is to drive SO forward, while SO is to drive programmers forward.

Moving every fun question here would either push people on meta that do not want to contribute to the meta discussion, or make the SO experience very dry.

Then should SU or SF fun questions be on meta too? I guess the audience they are targeted to, as with SO, are quite different, and therefore should be targeted specifically.

I already find it confusing to have SF specific FAQ in meta and would have kept that in the corresponding page, but can see the value of reducing redundance with the overlapping part and therefore have it all in meta.

But again, my main reason: meta has a small community with one purpose: to drive SO forward. Let's keep it that way.

Comment: Well, Meta is to drive all 3 sibling sites forward without prejudice ;-p But I think we know what you mean... SO the *platform* rather than SO the site...

Answer (score 7):

Many of the "fun" questions simply shouldn't *be*...

But there is a grey area...

If the "fun" is about the sites, then MSO may be appropriate. But it shouldn't be MSO just because it is "fun". If it is about programming the clearly SO, etc.

Answer (score 4):

No. "Fun" server questions go on ServerFault. "Fun" programming questions go on SO (albeit reluctantly) and "Fun" random computer related crap goes on SuperUser.

Meta is for site improvements and discussing how to get rid of "fun" questions.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7436/what-should-sos-motto-be/7438#7438): The first rule of StackOverflow is you do not talk about StackOverflow (you talk about Stack Overflow on Meta StackOverflow)

That said, it depends on how your "fun" question is perceived. They may migrate your "fun" question based on some criteria shared by two or more hi-reps, but hey, so long as your question isn't closed let them stick it in whichever overflow they want. Just have fun wherever.