# What should the Super User ads look like?

Tags: discussion, advertising

Last week, [Kyle Cronin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/658/kyle-cronin) noticed that we had put up some Server Fault ads (both on Stack Overflow and TDWTF) and started the [Love the new Server Fault ad!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14347/love-the-new-server-fault-ad) discussion. So my question is... what should the Super User ads look like?

If we go with the same look/concept as the Server Fault ads (i.e. the logo with fun copy), then what should the copy be?

There are a good amount of concepts to work with in the [original question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14347/love-the-new-server-fault-ad).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7436/what-should-sos-motto-be/7438#7438

Comment: I could keep throwing out more bad ideas, but I think I'll stop now. :)

Comment: @retracile: Thanks for the help. You've given me plenty of taglines to work with now ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

super**user** ... vigilante IT

super**user** ... taking IT into our own hands

Answer (score 8):

super **user** ... no that's NOT a cup holder

Answer (score 3):

**[**super**user**  ...`deltree /y c:\` and call me in the morning**}**

Comment: That'll work! I'll get one of those up...

Answer (score 2):

Something revolving around this:

[Alt text http://www.oddpic.com/data/528/death-by-keyboard.gif](http://www.oddpic.com/data/528/death-by-keyboard.gif)

If this doesn't surmise the agony felt by users who can't get something to work, I don't know what will.

Super User: Where Alex generates ad revenue *and* trolls for future content :)

Comment: That one looks different? I thought the dude banged his head on the keyboard. And I should note, no animation...

Comment: @Alex: You are right, I am just now noticing that this version of the gif has a lot of frames cut out. I am incredibly saddened now.

Comment: It's different to the original but it's still pretty good actually, makes it look like his brain went neuclear

Comment: With missing frames it looks more like TRON was unable to download the user without serious packet loss.

Comment: Here's a complete one. There's a keyboard error at the end I don't remember, but it otherwise seems complete: http://bbs.malkaviabbs.com/images/cerberus_themes/bloody_keyboard.gif

Comment: The image link is (effectively) broken (redirects to a generic page - domain name expired?).

Answer (score 2):

I insist--nay, demand--that all ads are accompanied by [this song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGu9yxdbFio).

Also, all text should be to the effect of:

```
[superuser: hell yeah}
```

Comment: ... nor sound ;-)

Comment: @Alex: Are you saying you *don't* like waffles?

Comment: @Eric: Well now that I think about it, I *do* like waffles... aw what the heck! Rules are meant to be broken! All SU ads will just blast this song!!

Comment: Hell yes, Alex! That's what Willis was talking about!

Answer (score 2):

Super**user**  ... because the computers *do* hate you.

Comment: Bam! This one is definitely in the mix.

Answer (score 2):

super**user** ...maybe a sledgehammer will fix it

Comment: Good stuff! Alternate: "...or you could just use a sledgehammer."

Comment: Yeah, I like that alternate; I think both work pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

...after you've turned it off and back on again.

Answer (score 2):

super **user** ... I *told* you, just freaking reboot already...

Answer (score 2):

super **user** ... Have you restarted your computer?

Answer (score 2):

super **user** ... Where is the any key?

Answer (score 2):

super **user** ... Because everyone is a user someday.

Answer (score 1):

super**user** ...have you tried reinstalling?

meh.

Answer (score 1):

super**user**  ... because IT will never guess what we did

super**user**  ... because IT will never guess you did it

super**user**  ... because those guys in IT are bored

super**user**  ... when you're tired of waiting for IT

Answer (score 1):

super **user** ... no, Mom, you don't belong here

Answer (score 1):

**[**super**user**  ...well what in the hell did you do that for?**}**

Answer (score 1):

**[**super**user**  ...Because this is what your IT Dept does when they don't answer your calls.**}**

Comment: just a bit too long... but i like the concept.

Comment: That's what your IT does when you're holding the line

Answer (score 1):

super**user** ...you're not hitting it hard enough.

Answer (score 1):

super **user** ... wheel

Answer (score 1):

super **user** ... Because I don't want to pay someone $60+/hr.

Answer (score 1):

super**user** - Because you really don't want to spend 2 hours on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

All Punch-The-Monkey, All The Time.

Answer (score 0):

Something revolving around this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [theburningbiscuit.com](http://www.theburningbiscuit.com/Pictures%20for%20site/Demotivational%20Posters/customercare.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Despair: How I made 10 bajillion dollars ripping off horrible business cliches.  Damn I'm jealous.