# StackOverflow LLC's motto is

Tags: discussion

I think [this Jeff Tweet](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/11889123232) should be a Meta question, so I'm open it here:

> *Google has "don't be evil"; we think Stack Overflow llc's is "leave the Internet better than we found it". Thoughts?*

Comment: So... are we going to RT here now?

Comment: I have no idea what "llc's" means, but if Jeff wants a better Internet, he shouldn't mess around by using twitter.

Comment: LLC means a limited-liability company in the US, but this q is about a (corporate) **motto** or slogan for Stack Overflow. (Someone consider tweaking the title a bit?) And the one Jeff suggested is not bad at all, in my opinion. :)

Comment: @Ladybug: 55 million people disagree with you

Comment: @Kop - Are you arguing that the 55 million people who are using twitter are trying to make the internet *better?*

Comment: @Kop, popularity doesn't mean it's right. IE Nickelback is popular and they most definitely are WRONG! (no personal argument about twitter though, I just don't use it)

Comment: For Stack Overflow the website (as opposed to Stack Overflow LLC), see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7436/what-should-sos-motto-be.

Comment: Cool "question" bro.

Comment: @mmyers: that's an unfortunate link; without the apostrophe it just reads *"What should SOS motto be?"* ... which is just obvious.

Comment: "Leave the Internet better than we found it" can't work. There's no intension here on leaving ...

Answer (score 8):

That's crazy talk. Stack Overflow is about filling the Internet with unicorns and waffles.

Oh wait, that was meta. Carry on!

Comment: But that *does* leave the Internet better than we found it.

Comment: @Jon: not if you prefer ponies and pancakes.

Comment: So when exactly did unicorns displace ponies? (And was there something ugly behind the scenes that we shouldn't know about? Unicorns are unfairly weaponized.)

Comment: @mmyers - TheTXI, who was the last remaining pony defender, has better things to do, and so the unicorn population remains unchecked, and ponies everywhere have long gone into hiding.

Comment: @mmyers There is no "fairness" in evolution. And unicorns displaced ponies after April 1st, when @baplpha's unicorns took the world by storm! (my wife even says "I see those damned unicorns everywhere now - on *my* sites!)

Comment: Who in the world is baplpha and how can I punish him for stealing my idea?

Comment: @Jared: But ponies are so much *cuter!*

Comment: @balpha He's the same guy who made my fingers type wrong. Jerk.

Answer (score 7):

StackOverflow LLC:

How smart people get things done.

Comment: With apologies to Joel Spolsky.

Comment: Why apologies?  That's an awesome motto.

Comment: I'd say "How smart people get nothing done." You know, going on SO from work, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow LLC is...

### Questions answered.

### Questions answered here.

### Questions? Answered.

### Got questions? Get answers.

### The business of answering questions.

Comment: *Questions answered* **here.**

Comment: @quack: Was thinking more that SO LLC isn't "here" but covers the whole Trilogy.

Comment: mmm... point, but "here" could also be taken to *mean* the whole Trilogy.  interpretation and perspective.

Answer (score 5):

To proactively facilitate and leverage visible synergistic value-adds to shift the paradigm of Web 3.0 inquiries by providing world-class leadership in the community-driven market space bandwidth.

--or--

To help get questions answered.

Comment: +1 'cause I'm really feeling the synergy.

Comment: I prefer the first one.

Answer (score 4):

I thought Joel's was "don't leave money on the table"

Comment: slip it under ?

Answer (score 4):

Motto:

> Providing Help, one answer at a time.

Answer (score 2):

"Don't be evil" is at least self-centered.

The "leave the Internet better than we found it" is a bit the idealistic "let's change the world, make it a better place, for you and for me".

In this case, SO is more pretentious than Google, claiming more control over the Internet than Google itself. Wanting to make it better or worse is still trying to control and change it.

Comment: Say what you mean: Jeff is megalomaniac!

Comment: Google having dont be evil is comical.

Comment: Now you sound like Micheal Jackson... "Heal the world!"

Answer (score 1):

You've got questions, we've got meta.

Comment: You've got questions, we've got a way to transfer you to superuser?

Comment: You've got questions, we've got close votes.

Comment: You've got questions, we've got Jon Skeet.

Comment: You've got questions, we've got flags

Comment: You've got Iceland, we've got Fridays.

Comment: You've got questions?  We have blank stares, then raucous laughter.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ask today, answer tomorrow.

Comment: Pshhht, we usually answer faster than that. 8-)

Comment: its more like - when you have to ask some question, come here and get answered and from next day, start answering other questions yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

The actual motto that the LLC came up with was "Make the Internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions", but maybe Jeff changed it because it didn't fit in the 140 character twitter limit.

Comment: Or maybe because it's a mouthful?